# inaccurate fundamental frequency(peak, pitch) with cepstrum of stft at high frequency

Tags: python, audio-processing

I'm trying to detect fundamental frequency of sound

I use cepstrum to find the frequency.

It works great except high frequency.

I want to detect highest frequency of piano, C8(4186Hz)

However, to detect 4186Hz with sample rate 44100, I need quefrency 10.5 which is impossible since quefrency is number of sample.

so I get 10 quefrency, and 44100/10 = 4410 Hz which close to C#8(4435Hz)

How should I detect accurate fundamental frequency.

**Edit:**

```
samplerate, samples = wav.read(audiopath)
print "samplerate= " + str(samplerate)
samples = (samples[:, 0] + samples[:, 1]) / 2
overlapFac = 0.9
s = stft(samples, binsize, overlapFac)

break_flag = False
fund_freq_list = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    ceps = np.fft.irfft(np.power(np.log(np.abs(s[i])), 2))      
    for nan in np.isnan(ceps):      
        if nan:
            break_flag = True
            break

    if break_flag:
        break

    plt.plot(ceps)


    ignore_begin = int(samplerate/4500 - 2)
    ceps = ceps[ignore_begin:]


    for under_zero in ceps:
        if under_zero < 0:
            under_zero = np.where(ceps == under_zero)[0][0]
            break


    print "under_zero = " + str(under_zero+ignore_begin)


    ceps = ceps[under_zero:int(samplerate/27.5 + 2)]
    hertz = str(samplerate/float(ceps.argmax() + under_zero + ignore_begin))
    print "hertz = " + hertz
    print "sec = %3.3f ~ %3.3f" % (float((binsize*i*(1-overlapFac)))/float((samplerate)), float((binsize*(i+1)*(1-overlapFac)))/float((samplerate)))
    print "val = " + str(ceps.max())
    print "--------------------"

    fund_freq_list.append({'s_num': i, 'hertz': float(hertz)})
```

Comment: You should add your code as an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In general, cepstral methods are not as accurate at higher audio pitch estimation as compared to other pitch estimation methods.

Comment: @hotpaw2 what are other pitch estimation methods I can use for high freq?